# How much is an airliner's drag coefficient?

Tags: aerodynamics, drag

How much is an airliner's Cd, using the frontal area as reference point. I want to compare values with cars and others objects, tear drops, cube etc.

Is Cd measured at zero lift AoA or when the plane is flying in a straight line?

Answer (score 1):

> Is Cd measured at zero lift AoA or when the plane is flying in a straight line?

Both.

$C_D$ is a function, not a number.

The "numbers" are the partial derivatives: $C_{D_\alpha}$ measures how $C_D$ changes w.r.t. the angle of attack $\alpha$, for example.

Comment: How much is an airliner's Cd, using the frontal area as reference point?

Comment: @Aeolus it depends on the speed, the AoA, the sideslip, the rates, the configuration